# I can use form inputs without ref and jnChange?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have simple form

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

const mySubmitForm = event => {
  event.preventDefault();
  const form = event.target;
  form.firstName.classList.add("red");
  console.log("This is first name value", (form.firstName.className = "red"));
  console.log("This is last name value", form.lastName);
  console.log("This is email value", form.email);
  console.log("This is password", form.password);
};

const App = (props) => {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <form onSubmit={mySubmitForm}>
          <fieldset>
            <legend>Форма регистрации</legend>
            Your name:{" "}
            <input
              className={this.state.isChangeClass ? "red" : ""}
              type="text"
              name="firstName"
            />
            Your last name: <input type="text" name="lastName" />
            Your email: <input type="text" name="email" />
            Your password: <input type="password" name="password" />
            <input type="submit" value="Send" />
          </fieldset>
        </form>

   </div>
    );
}
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Sometimes to me don't need controlled input forms, especially when i have a lot of fields, can i use this method for send my form without refs and state(onChange), it's normal practice for optimization my React application?

Comment: Yes, it is normal practice.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can. Its a completely valid syntax and you can use it as long as any change does not require a **re-render**. (Like if one field has a dependency and updates or blocks any action like display a error message when field value changes or on blur)